# Porting creation of a PDF document from iOS to Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, pdf-generation, core-graphics

I am porting my code from iPhone to Mac and I have no idea how I can do this in Mac. Here's my code that I am trying to convert and I know that there's no UIGraphic in Mac. Can someone point me to a guide or give me a quick hint? Thanks.

```
NSString *newFilePath = @"path/to/your/newfile.pdf";
NSString *templatePath = @"path/to/your/template.pdf";

//create empty pdf file;
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newFilePath, CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 612), nil);

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, (CFStringRef)templatePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

//open template file
CGPDFDocumentRef templateDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
CFRelease(url);

//get amount of pages in template
size_t count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(templateDocument);

//for each page in template
for (size_t pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= count; pageNumber++) {
    //get bounds of template page
    CGPDFPageRef templatePage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(templateDocument, pageNumber);
    CGRect templatePageBounds = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(templatePage, kCGPDFCropBox);

    //create empty page with corresponding bounds in new document
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(templatePageBounds, nil);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //flip context due to different origins
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, templatePageBounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    //copy content of template page on the corresponding page in new file
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, templatePage);

    //flip context back
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, templatePageBounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    /* Here you can do any drawings */
    [@"Test" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 300) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(templateDocument);
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `CGPDFContextCreateWithURL` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile` (the parameters are very similar). To begin/end pages, use `CGPDFContextBeginPage` and `CGPDFContextEndPage`. When you're done, call `CGPDFContextClose` instead of `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext`.

The rest can remain the same – Core Graphics exists on both iOS and Mac OS X – which also means that you could use the functions I've mentioned above on iOS as well if you want to use the same code on both platforms.

Comment: Thanks man! I need to settle down and read the Quartz2D Programming guide for once...

Comment: Any chance you have since done this in Swift? I'm looking for an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4, macOS High Sierra Update

```
func generatePdfWithFilePath(thefilePath: String)
    {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: thefilePath) as CFURL

        guard let currentContext = CGContext(url, mediaBox: nil, documentInfo as CFDictionary) else {
            return
        }
        self.context = currentContext

        self.context!.beginPDFPage(pageInfo as CFDictionary)

        drawReport()

        self.context!.endPDFPage()


        // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
        self.context!.closePDF()

        self.context = nil
        //DebugLog("generatePdfWithFilePath() completed")
    }
```