# Objective-C cocoa create PDF from txt

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf-generation, porting

I am porting my iOS App to MAC-OS and I am stopped because I cannot create a PDF file programmatically.

What I need to do is to create a PDF from a given .txt file

My code in ios version is this:

```
- (void) createPDF:(NSString *)fileName withContent:(NSString *)content forSize:(int)fontSize andFont:(NSString *)font andColor:(NSColor *)color{
CGRect a4Page = CGRectMake(0, 0, DOC_WIDTH, DOC_HEIGHT);

NSDictionary *fileMetaData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

if (!UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, a4Page, fileMetaData )) {
    NSLog(@"error creating PDF context");
    return;
}

BOOL done = NO;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSelectFont (context, [font cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], fontSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
// Initialize an attributed string.
CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, currentRange, (CFStringRef)content);

// Create the framesetter with the attributed string.
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);

do {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(LEFT_MARGIN,
                               TOP_MARGIN,
                               DOC_WIDTH - RIGHT_MARGIN - LEFT_MARGIN,
                               DOC_HEIGHT - TOP_MARGIN - BOTTOM_MARGIN);

    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, bounds);



    // Create the frame and draw it into the graphics context
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, path, NULL);

    if(frame) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, bounds.origin.y);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -(bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height));
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        // Update the current range based on what was drawn.
        currentRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frame);
        currentRange.location += currentRange.length;
        currentRange.length = 0;

        CFRelease(frame);
    }

    // If we're at the end of the text, exit the loop.
    if (currentRange.location == CFAttributedStringGetLength((CFAttributedStringRef)attrString))
        done = YES;
}
while(!done);

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();}
```

XCode gives to me a lot of warnings and errors:

Errors: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Warnings: Implicit declaration of function 'UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile' is invalid in C99 [for example]

Could someone help me to find a solution to my problem?

I tried to use CGPDFContextCreateWithURL but I didn't get any result

Thank you all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Porting creation of a PDF document from iOS to Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050124/porting-creation-of-a-pdf-document-from-ios-to-mac-os-x)

Comment: I've tried to get the answer from "Porting creation of a PDF document from iOS to Mac OS X"  but I'm not able to understand how to apply the suggestions to my case

Comment: The issue is that the API for PDF creation is probably different in OSX and iOS. You will need to find the corresponding iOS functions and use them instead of the calls that generate the error

Comment: Please update the question with the macOS code you have so far and tell us what the issues are.